# I can't set an upper bound for the Result parameter of an AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, generics, android-asynctask, upperbound

I'm trying to set an upper bound to the Result parameter of an AsyncTask like so:

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<T, Long, V extends Model>
```

The compiler is complaining that 'extends is not expected, it's expecting a comma.

I have tried writing Model as an abstract class and as a regular class.

Any ideas?

Thank you, 
David

Comment: Is that a typo here, or do you actually have `calls` instead of `class`?

Comment: ...yes that was a typo.  I've edited the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `T` and `V` are unresolved type parameters, `MyTask` needs to be parameterized on them. Try declaring the following:

```
public class MyTask<T, V extends Model> extends AsyncTask<T, Long, V>
```

I also changed `calls` to `class` - I assume that was a typo.

**In response to your comment:**

```
MyTask<T, V extends Model>
```

Here, `MyClass` is *declaring* the type parameters `T` and `V`. When type parameters are declared they can optionally be *bounded* with `extends`. `T` isn't bounded - it can be any reference type. `V` has an *upper bound* of `Model`. - it must be some type that is or extends `Model`.

```
extends AsyncTask<T, Long, V>
```

Like any declaration for a class not extending `Object`, this is saying that `MyTask` extends `AsyncTask` - I'm sure you understand that much. [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) has three type parameters: in its declaration they are called `Params`, `Progress`, and `Result`. Here, `MyTask` is providing those type parameters with *type arguments* - `T`, `Long`, and `V`.

So `MyTask` is keeping `Params` as an unbounded type parameter, *resolving* `Progress` with the concrete type `Long`, and bounding `Result` with `Model`.

See the [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) for a good introduction to generics. Then see [Angelika Langer's Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html) for further questions.

Comment: Thanks, but I' not sure what the difference is.  Why can you extend on the child class but not the base class?  Does it matter that you omitted the Progress parameter?